# How can you return the last value in common lisp

Tags: return, lisp, common-lisp

I know that the values function helps control REPL but I want to explicitly return the last value from a function.
The only thing close to that I managed to find to what i was looking for is

```
 (setf (values q a) (floor 1.5))
```

But I am only interested in the 0.5 that it returns.
My question is how can I only return the last value of a function not just the second but the n-th value(whichever it maybe)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard operator to get the last value, or even to iterate over values, but you can work around that using [`MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_multip.htm):

```
(defun last-arg (&rest args)
  (first (last args)))

(defmacro multiple-value-last (form)
  `(multiple-value-call #'last-arg ,form))

(multiple-value-last (floor 1.5))
; => 0.5
(multiple-value-last (values 10 20 30))
; => 30
```

At least on SBCL the standard [`MULTIPLE-VALUE-LIST`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_mult_1.htm) seems to be implemented this way.

Comment: Curiously I couldn't immediately see that this is safe according to the spec (obviously it *is* safe): it looks as if there is nothing constraining `multiple-values-limit` to be smaller or equal to `call-arguments-limit`.  I have probably misread the spec, but if that's right then I'm sure that's a deficiency in the spec because there really ought to be such a constraint.

Comment: I think my comment above is wrong: if `values` is a function (it's an accessor, but what it isn't is a special operator) then there *is* a constraint on the number of multiple values which is that it can be no more than the number of arguments you can pass to it, which is `call-arguments-limit`.

Comment: well now I know one thing for sure it's time to move on to macros thanks!

Comment: When I see `(last-value expr)` it doesn't hint at all that it is a macro nor that it has something to do with multiple values and not eg. lists or arrays. Perhaps naming it `multiple-value-last` will make it less surprising and simpler to assimilate. (Yes, I know of `nth-value` and I think Pierson/Pitman choose a bad name)

Comment: @Sylwester Yeah, I see your point. I chose the name originally to be consistent with `NTH-VALUE` (and same with `VALUES` vs `MULTIPLE-VALUES`), but `MULTIPLE-VALUE-LAST` is probably a better choice.